# Help with URL rewrite (REGEX?) following J3 to J4 migration

Tags: joomla-4.x

Up against it at the minute so my brain seems to be going off in the wrong direction.

I have migrated a very large site from J3 to J4. The J3 article URL's look like the below:

> /133-locally/1984-ukraine-how-lymington-and-the-new-forest-can-help

The URL to be directed to in J4 is:

> /locally/ukraine-how-lymington-and-the-new-forest-can-help

ReDJ is not J4 compatible so I think I can only do this using a catch all htaccess rule to remove numbers and the trailing dash at the start of each part of the URL.

I do have one other minor URL issue which I'm hoping direct alias will fix but so far it's not working. The above is my main problem.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm now reading your question and comments correctly, what you're looking for is some htaccess rewrite rules that will redirect requests that include ids to the URLs that don't have ids - a request to `/133-locally/1984-ukraine-how-lymington-and-the-new-forest-can-help` should be redirected to `/locally/ukraine-how-lymington-and-the-new-forest-can-help`.

These should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On

#exclude images and media folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(images/|media/)
RewriteRule . - [S=4]

#Requests in format /133-locally/1984-ukraine-how-lymington-and-the-new-forest-can-help
RewriteRule ^(?:\d+-)([^\/]*)\/(?:\d+-)(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]

#Requests in format /133-locally
RewriteRule ^(?:\d+-)([^\/]*)(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]

#Requests in format /news/133-locally/1984-ukraine-how-lymington-and-the-new-forest-can-help
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:\/\d+-)([^\/]*)\/(?:\d+-)(.*)$ /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]

#Requests in format /news/133-locally
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:\/\d+-)([^\/]*)(.*)$ /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Using all four rules should result in redirection for categories and articles either linked to the root or within a menu item/subdirectory.

Additional rules would be required if there are any nested categories in use, e.g. `/133-locally/1234-community-support/1984-ukraine-how-lymington-and-the-new-forest-can-help`

Comment: This works perfectly for the articles, but is affecting the image directory as well - is there a method to prevent it change the URL's for images? I.e. we have a folder /images/1-intropages which redorects to /images/intropages.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a rule that skips the redirection for anything within the images or media folders.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've another issue, I can only assume is due to a change in how URL's are generated in J4. I'll create a new question for it now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those URLs have been produced by the Category/Article system in Joomla, the IDs for both can be removed by switching on the `Remove IDs from URLs` option in the Content Options

Content -> Articles -> Options -> Integration -> Remove IDs from URLs

Comment: I understand that - the old site has 100's of pages using the old structure with the id's in them - the new site does not add the id's with or without that being selected. Thus I think a regex htaccess rewrite is needed.

Comment: If changing the option mentioned in this post does not add the ID for the record then you potentially have some other extension fiddling with the routing or maybe something in the older .htaccess if you have carried it over from the J3 instance that you may need to resolve first.

Answer (score 0):

The core Redirect system that comes with Joomla could be used to trap the incoming URL and updated to redirect to the non-id version of the url. You will find it under Plugin on the System dashboard for Joomla 4.

Depending on the number of articles as to whether that is practical though for your site.

Using Redirect or manipulating the url is not really a long term solution in my view, you really need to get search engines to index your site using the new url for your articles as soon as possible and then you are just dealing with bookmarks and site links to be updated.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the problem - there are 100's of pages that use the numbers within the site which after migrating to Joomla 4 the ids no longer show even with id switched on under setting in articles. Thus i need a catch all to redirect all of these many pages so they do not end on 404. Yes adding one at a time would work but there are 100's of them. I'm not joomla novice, i just do not have also tof experience with regex rediects.